# jQuery document .ready and .resize in Wordpress

Tags: jquery

Rather than repeat all my code for resize page, I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(myfunction);
$(window).resize(myfunction);

function myfunction() {
    // do whatever
}
```

I'm having some issues.  I have some things that need to happen just when page loads (are always same) and some things that need to move on resize.  My page is setup like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    //a bunch of static stuff here

    $wall.imagesLoaded(function(){
       //using an imagesloaded plugin
       //masonry is here & needs to reload on resize.
    });

});
```

I read somewhere to always put that jQuery at the beginning for Wordpress, so I figured I might as well, since it worked.  How do I jiggle the rest so Masonry will reload on window resize?

Thanks!

**Edit for a solution: This is working for Wordpress.**

```
    (function($) {

    $(document).ready(documentReadyFunction);
    $(window).resize(windowResizeFunction);

    function documentReadyFunction() {
        // functions for document ready
        onPageLoadOrResize();
        onPageLoad();
    }

    function windowResizeFunction() {
        // functions for window resize
        onPageLoadOrResize();
    }

    function onPageLoad() {
        alert("pageload");
    }


    function onPageLoadOrResize () {
        alert ("Load or Resize");
    }

    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Why not using `isResizable` option? http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/options.html#isresizable

Comment: Ah well, without an example (none in page?), I have no idea how to use it.  I'm just changing number of columns on win resize.  Plus, I need to learn the answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a pattern like this:

```
$(document).ready(documentReadyFunction);
$(window).resize(windowResizeFunction);

function documentReadyFunction() {
    genericStuffFunction()
    // do whatever for document ready
}

function windowResizeFunction() {
    genericStuffFunction()
    // do whatever for window resize
}

function genericStuffFunction() {
    // do whatever for document ready and window resize
}
```

Comment: I get an error in console "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function line 2 (the window resize part).  Is it because it's in Wordpress?  I need no-conflict mode or something?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could have your `myFunction` accept an `ev` (event) parameter, and then check the `ev.type` property to see whether it's `resize` and run the code accordingly, like so:

```
$(document).ready(myfunction);
$(window).resize(myfunction);

function myfunction(ev, ui) {
    if (ev.type && ev.type == 'resize') {
        alert('resize');
    }

    // do main stuff here...
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/ynwsc/)